# Is there a function to calculate the center of mass of a hexahedron

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to calculate the center of mass for a hexahedron. I have a set of eight coordinates. I tried using the function  ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(coords_vol) but it seems not to work. Please any suggestion?
This is my code:

```
coords = np.array([
          [0.,0.,0.],\
          [10.,0.,0.],\
          [10.,10.,0.],\
          [10.,10.,10.],\
          [0.,10.,10.],\
          [0.,0.,10.],\
          [0.,10.,0.],\
          [10.,0.,10.],\
          ])

CM = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(coords_vol)
```